# How to make threads with functions: C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++

I'm trying to make threads using C++'s standard library via functions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

void print()
{
    printf("PRINT\n");
    printf("PRINT2\n");
}

void createThread() 
{
    thread newThread(print);
}

int main()
{
    createThread();
    cin.get();
}
```

the program compiles and runs but once the thread is finished it creates a "debug error". Any thoughts?

Comment: You're not supposed to use `printf` in a thread subroutine

Comment: What sort of "debug error"?  Is there a message?  Does the program misbehave?

Comment: @stackptr - says who?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your thread object goes out of scope before you call its `detach()` or `join()` member.

Try this:

```
int main()
{
    thread newThread(print);
    ...
    newThread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your "debug error" means the compiler error message, you should check if `-pthread` flag is set. That is compile the code with

```sh
$ g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -pthread -o main
```

If your "debug error" means the runtime error, you should remember to `join()` after you create a thread.

source code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void print()
{
    std::cout << "PRINT"   << std::endl;;
    std::cout << "PRINT 2" << std::endl;;
}

void create_thread()
{
    std::thread print_thread(print);
    print_thread.join();  // remember to join()
}

int main()
{
    create_thread();
    return 0;
}
```

In addition, you may pay attention to 4 additional points:

1. `using namespace std` is not recommended.
2. remember to `join()` after you create a thread
3. `return 0` for main()
4. `printf()` is in stdio.h. use `std::cout` for iostream